# Curl request in thread double free

Tags: c, curl, pthreads, malloc, free

i have a problem with problem when i run N threads and in every thread i make request using curl read response to `char*` allocate dynamiclly. **Sometimes** when i free response i have error `double free or corruption (fasttop)`. Code below:

```
static void* crawler_threadHandler(void* _arg) 
{
    size_t thisId = (size_t)_arg;
    crawler_thread* thisThread = &crawler.threads[thisId];
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (crawler.prepareRequestCommon != NULL)
    {
        crawler.prepareRequestCommon(curl);
    }

    while(thisThread->stopRequest == false)
    {
        crawler_runRequest(curl);

        sleep(1);
    }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    thisThread->isRunning = false;

    return NULL;
}

static void crawler_runRequest(CURL* curl)
{
    CURLcode res;
    struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;
    char* response = (char*) malloc(1);

    if (crawler.prepareRequestEach != NULL)
    {
        crawler.prepareRequestEach(curl, headers);
    }

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, crawler_reponseWriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void*) response);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_slist_free_all(headers);

    if(res != CURLE_OK)
    {
        fprintf(
            stderr, 
            "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
            curl_easy_strerror(res)
        );
    }
    else
    {
        if (crawler.parseResponse != NULL)
        {
            crawler.parseResponse(response);
        }
    }

    if (response != NULL)
    {
        free(response); //Here is crash
    }
}

static size_t crawler_reponseWriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;

    userp = realloc(userp, realsize + 1);

    if (userp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(
            stderr, 
            "No space left in head for allocate response, bytes: %zu\n", 
            realsize
        );
        realsize = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        char terminateNull = '\0';
        memcpy(userp, contents, realsize);
        memcpy(userp + realsize, &terminateNull, 1);
    }

    return realsize;
}
```

Function `crawler_threadHandler` is pthread handler call by

```
errno = pthread_create(&thread.pthread, NULL, crawler_threadHandler, (void*) i);
```

I mean sometimes crash: when i run 3 threads crash occurs 1 or 2 times.

Please help i have no idea where is a bug.

Edit: Works after changes:

```
//crawler_runRequest
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void*) &response);

...

//crawler_reponseWriteCallback
void** responsePtr = userp;
*responsePtr = realloc(*responsePtr, realsize + 1);

...

memcpy(*responsePtr, contents, realsize);
memcpy(*responsePtr + realsize, &terminateNull, 1);
```

Comment: `userp = realloc(userp, realsize + 1);` - that's a terrible idea. The value you're assigning here is lost once this callback returns for the next frame of a download. I strongly suspect `crawler.prepareRequestEach(curl, headers);` suffers from a similar fate, btw, but have no way of knowing for sure since this is far, far from a [mcve].

Comment: What is the code for ```crawler.parseResponse()``` ?

Comment: @vasile_t this is poiter to function with `printf("Parsing ...\n");`
@WhozCraig I know but there shouldn't be any value only this: `char* response = (char*) malloc(1);`

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm talking about. If that undergoes a genuine realloc, the *caller* (which is CURL, btw, you gave it the value of that pointer when setting the writecallback data; remember?) is left with a pointer that is no longer valid for *anything*, which it will happily pass back to you on the *next* invoke of your callback, and you'l just-as-happily send it to `realloc`, where you meet *undefined behavior* as your reward.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you, now i understand, i must do it in other way.

Comment: I advise you provide a pointer to pointer for *both* of the cases I mentioned (the header builder and the callback), and code those to dereference the pointer-to-pointer to allow modification of the caller-side pointer. If any of that seemed like a foreign language you probably need to study more on passing pointers by-addres to C functions). Its not hard, but takes a little getting used to, and in the end it will seem completely normal.